# The right way to use Machine Learning to predict latitude and longitude

Tags: machine-learning, geostatistics, gis

There are some simple ML techniques that can be used to easily predict latitude/longitude co-ordinates, such as predicting the latitude and longitude separately using two different models. However, I get the sense that this is a simple hack that doesn't give the best results. To quote another [paper](http://www.academia.edu/4489774/PREDICTING_THE_GEOGRAPHIC_ORIGIN_OF_WORLD_MUSIC):

> Most regression
>   methods assume either that either only one real number is to be
>   predicted, or if multiple real numbers are to be predicted that they
>   are independent. The problem of predicting a point on the surface of a
>   sphere is more complicated as the latitudes and longitudes involved
>   are not independent.

Unfortunately, the authors of the linked paper just side-step the issue by using kNN. I'd like to use supervised learning with some non-geographical inputs (strings, numbers, etc...) to predict a latitude/longitude co-ordinate, and I'd like to approach it using "best practices" rather than a simple hack. How should I go about it? Any links to any papers or blog posts would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: von Mises distribution is a good fit for modeling data on circle and on sphere by extension.

Comment: [Here's a question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172792/) with more detail on von Mises and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't just potential interdependence of latitudes and longitudes; it's that the scales wrap around. On a circle 359 degrees and 1 degree are quite close. A general term for this type of problem is [directional statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_statistics).

One way to start with analysis of spatial data would be to go over the [CRAN Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html) on that topic. That page details the many R packages available for handling spatial data, analyzing point patterns, doing spatial regression, etc. Documentation for R packages that seem related to your specific interests will typically include helpful references to related literature.

Comment: As if things weren't complicated enough! Now I have to deal with spatial autocorrelation AND the scales wrapping around! :)

Comment: A little additional info that might be helpful: according to [another question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/36145/linear-regression-and-spatial-autocorrelation?rq=1), there is a [book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387781716) about spatial data analysis in R. This book might be helpful for those hoping to learn about this kind of thing.

Comment: Both answers have some useful information, but I've ultimately decided to mark this answer as the correct one. I think that when trying to do machine learning/regression with a lat/lon as the output (rather than the input), this answer is more relevant.