# Is inference about interior bear population from observation boundary an un"bear"able estimation problem?

Tags: estimation, biostatistics, geostatistics

The following map shows a density-coloured grid of observations of [American black bear](https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/41638-Ursus-americanus) reported on [iNaturalist](https://www.inaturalist.org). In the top half of the province you can see a loose boundary of observations around an interior region. This boundary is due to observations tending to be done along highways 16, 29, 37, and 97 that bound this interior region. If you look closely at the online map, you will find that not every observation is exactly on the highway. But for modelling purposes we might suppose that "close to the highway" for some definition of close given by a distance will be suitable for defining our boundary.

[image]

---

It may be beneficial to leverage knowledge about the natural history of the American black bear, so we might consider obtaining additional data for the purposes of a modelling.

What we have:

- iNaturalist locations and times of observations of American black bear and other species inside the boundary

What we could get:

- Topographical model of interior region
- Climate/weather data within or interpolated within interior region

---

Suppose that a bear being in the boundary is always transient. That is, it will either exit to the exterior or enter the interior. This is plausible provided that we make the boundary region small compared to the mobility and typical [home range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_range) size of a bear.

With this assumption, I explored a train of thought utilizing the [Generalized Stokes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Stokes_theorem) with little success. More model assumptions seem to be required.

A simpler notion is that those observations at the boundary speak to an absolute amount of change in the interior population. If a bear either enters the interior or exist the exterior from the boundary, then those observations are related to the rates of change of the population. We would have to be careful that a bear could start in the exterior, and return to the exterior or alternatively start in the interior and return to the interior. So we cannot simply take the total number of observations as a flux/flow from the interior. But perhaps this is still a fruitful direction to explore.

---

Leaving aside the quality/reliability of the observations themselves (e.g. is that really black bear poop, or decayed moose poop), there is a large challenge with the sampling distribution. At a minimum, the observations are conditioned on people being there to make the observation and then subsequently post it to iNaturalist. People do not travel randomly, and there is likely (in a subjective probability sense) seasonality in when people tend to be along those aforementioned highways. Having recently started contributing to iNaruralist myself, I cannot say what led me to join now rather than sooner or later. I believe that only a minority of bear crossings on the boundary are observed by humans, and a minority of those observations are subsequently reported on iNaturalist.The bottom line of this train of thought is that we do not have any of the introductory textbook sample designs, and that we must instead humbly avoid making inferences or take on additional model assumptions.

---

What, if anything, can we infer about the interior density or probability mass?

Comment: These data tell us far more about where people are than where bears are. You need to model the *observational intensity.* A standard method uses this model to estimate probabilities in a Hansen-Hurwitz estimator.  See Steven Thompson's *Sampling* for details.